# Giving images to different cells of tableview

Tags: swift

I have a tableview in a collectionView having 5 sections and each section has 10 rows. Each cell has to be given different images.I am new to ios and have very less idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

Design A custom tableviewcell with a Image View, in Tableview's datasource Method -cellForRowAtIndexpath : assign image on imageView as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I gave all that. I get different images in the cells of a single row. But all the rows seems to same. Same images are displayed in all the rows. I want is different images in every cells irrespective of the row